# Isotope: Dynamic JSON loaded from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-isotope

What I would like to do is load and use data from a Google Spreadsheet JSON to populate a Isotope list, but the animation and sorting functionality stops functioning once I add the JSON (I have verified that the JSON/Javascript for loading it works, but I have absolutely no clue how to solve this problem. On researching, I did find [A CODE](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/342) that allows for the Isotope to load elements from a JSON file and still function, however I'm still learning my way through Javascript and I'm not sure how to integrate my Google Spreadsheet JSON into that solution. I know that it's probably something very simple, but anyone who helps me will have my deepest gratitude. Thank you!

**EDIT:** Here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/changmin/eq32fo5r/) with my code!

```
    function importFST(json) {
    for (i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
        entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        $('.isotope').append('<div class="element-item' + + entry.gsx$alpha.$t + '"><a href="http://' + entry.gsx$url.$t + '.domain.com/" title="' + entry.gsx$skill.$t + '">' + entry.gsx$name.$t + '</a> | "' + entry.gsx$living.$t + '"' + ' | <em>' + entry.gsx$mutation.$t + '</em></div>');
    }
}

$( function() {
  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    getSortData: {
      name: '.name',
      alliance: '.alliance',
      number: '.number parseInt',
      category: '[data-category]'
    }
  });

  // filter functions
  var filterFns = {
    // show if name ends with -a
    a: function() {
      var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
      return name.match( /a$/ );
    }
  };

  // bind filter button click
  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });

  // bind sort button click
  $('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
    $container.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Isotope looks very interesting indeed :-)  I have never used but I looked at the documentation (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html), and I'd try appending the elements in Isotype style in the JSON response for loop: $container.isotope()
  .append( elem )
  .isotope( 'appended', elem )
  .isotope('layout');  instead of using the container.appendChild(element); style. Well, like I said I have never used Isotope, but I'd try this. Good Luck anyway :-)

Comment: The posted code is from the isotope example you link to, not your code. What is your code?

Comment: @Macsupport Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/changmin/eq32fo5r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was a missing space between 'element-item' and entry.gsx$alpha.$t. This resulted in your isotope items having a classes like element-itemaaa, element-itembbb etc. You need to add a space to make sure the *itemSelector: '.element-item'*

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2aLrs0/)

here is my code (altered from yours a bit, with using isotope appended):

```
  function importFST(json) {
   // init  
  for (i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
    entry = json.feed.entry[i];
    var $newElems = $('<div class="element-item' + ' ' + entry.gsx$alpha.$t + '"><a href="http://' + entry.gsx$url.$t + '.domain.com/" title="' + entry.gsx$skill.$t + '">' + entry.gsx$name.$t + '</a> | ' + entry.gsx$living.$t + ' | <em>' + entry.gsx$mutation.$t + '</em></div>');

        var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layout: 'fitRows',
    getSortData: {
        name: '.name',
        alliance: '.alliance',
        number: '.number parseInt',
        category: '[data-category]'
    }
});
// filter functions
var filterFns = {
    // show if name ends with -a
    a: function () {
        var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
        return name.match(/a$/);
    }
};

// bind filter button click
$('#filters').on('click', 'button', function () {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({
        filter: filterValue
    });
});

// bind sort button click
$('#sorts').on('click', 'button', function () {
    var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
    $container.isotope({
        sortBy: sortByValue
    });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each(function (i, buttonGroup) {
    var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
    $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function () {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    });
});

   $('.isotope').append($newElems).isotope( 'appended', $newElems );

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will come back to vote up as soon as I have enough reputation. This really helped me. :)